# Is it possible to develop a Web Service using Visual Web Developer 2010?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, visual-web-developer-2010

Is it possible to develop an ASP.NET Web Service using the Visual Web Developer 2010? Or I must use Visual Studio itself for creating the Web Service?

Thanks,

LS Developer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. But for future understanding, please consider these notes:

1. Creating Web Service actually doesn't need any IDE. You can create a web service (or an entire web site) using Notepad. Therefore, Visual Studio is just a helpful tool for you.
2. Creating a web service based on **.NET Framework** actually needs you to compile your code. Therefore, you can again create the web service with notepad, and compile it using C# or VB.NET compiler, deploy it and use it.
3. Visual Web Developer 2010 (Express) is just an IDE. Web Service on the other hand is an **Item Template** (which writes the basic infrastructure for you). But even if you don't use that **Item Template**, you can create a class, inherit from **WebService** and create your web service.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Yes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wbhsy70.aspx

Comment: In Visual Web Developer 2010, the Web Service template is not available under Add New project.But there is another way.First create an empty ASP.NET Web Application and then Add - New Item and choose Web Service.There the Web service template is available.